# How can I find out why my XML file is already in use?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, file-io

when I write the XML file to hard drive using the following code

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("D:\\project\\data.xml");
    if (!Directory.Exists("D:\\project_elysian\\data\\" + System.DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")))
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\\project_elysian\\data\\" + System.DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    }
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("D:\\project_elysian\\data\\" + System.DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "\\" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss") + ".xml", null);
    XmlTextWriter writerlatest = new XmlTextWriter("D:\\project\\data\\latest\\today.xml", null);
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    writerlatest.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    doc.Save(writer);
    doc.Save(writerlatest);
    doc = null;
    writer.Flush();
    writerlatest.Flush();
```

it writes the XML file as desired but after that when I try to read that XML file in the same asp.net page (code placed in a C# Code Behind file) using the following code, it gives an error

```
    string filename = "D:\\project\\data\\latest\\today.xml";

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(searchResult));
    serializer.UnknownNode += new XmlNodeEventHandler(serializer_UnknownNode);
    serializer.UnknownAttribute += new XmlAttributeEventHandler(serializer_UnknownAttribute);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
```

the error is as follows

```
The process cannot access the file 'D:\project\data\latest\today.xml' because it is being used by another process.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\project\data\latest\today.xml' because it is being used by another process.
```

EDIT: The file isn't being used by any other process

Comment: Apparently you already have the file opened somewhere (without sharing)... you can't open it again until it is closed as the error suggests... where's the confusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're closing your writer with a call like `writer.Close();`

Answer (score 2):

The file is being used by yourself. You have to Close or dispose the XmlTextWriter object after using them.

```
public class XmlTextWriter : XmlWriter
{..}
public abstract class XmlWriter : IDisposable
{..}
```

implementing IDisposable tells user. I use some unmanaged resource please call Dispose to release them. 　refer to msdn: [IDisposable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx)

A shortcut is using which provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects. for example:

```
using (System.IO.FileStream fs =
    new System.IO.FileStream("c:\\file.txt",
        System.IO.FileMode.Open),
        fs2 =
    new System.IO.FileStream("c:\\file2.txt",
        System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    // do something here
}
```

Above code comes from:　[DISPOSE WITH USING](http://blog.dmbcllc.com/2008/11/10/dispose-with-using/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the file as you open using xmlwriter, it doesn't close the file automatically. In simple words if your file is open using other process you can't open it again till that file closed manually using your code.