# XML serializer file already in use error?

Tags: c#, serialization

when I try to use the following code in the codebehind file, it runs successfully but when I refresh the ASP.NET webform it gives an error of file already in use, the error is given below the code.

```
    string filename = "D:\\project\\data\\latest\\today.xml";
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(searchResult));

    serializer.UnknownNode += new XmlNodeEventHandler(serializer_UnknownNode);
    serializer.UnknownAttribute += new XmlAttributeEventHandler(serializer_UnknownAttribute);

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);

    searchResult po;

    po = (searchResult)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
```

## Here is the error

> The process cannot access the file 'D:\project\data\latest\today.xml' because it is being used by another process.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\project\data\latest\today.xml' because it is being used by another process.

## Error Source

> Line 141:        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML file already in use, please help me out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306443/xml-file-already-in-use-please-help-me-out)

Comment: Do what you did in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306443/xml-file-already-in-use-please-help-me-out

Comment: if you see the questions thoroughly both the problems are different, in one case I was writing the file also, and then trying to read, but in this case I was just reading this single file twice, in .NET this stuff matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you use a stream to open a file there's a chance that you lock the file so that no other stream can reach the file.You should close your streams as fast as possible.

I'd prefer to use the using keyword every time I am working with an IDisposable object.

I mean :

```
using(var fs=OpenFile(filename))
{
//do my work
fs.close();
}
```

in this manner even if I forget to close my stream it will be disposed finally and will be closed anyway.